# How to decline recurring Outlook meetings beyond a certain date?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I can attend some of the meetings I have been sent, but beyond a point in time, this will not be possible. Therefore I would like to remove all the meetings beyond this date.

Seemingly the only options are

- decline all
- decline one

The only solution I can think of is to wait until the last meeting has occurred, then remove the series, but why should I have to do that?

**EDIT**: some people seem to have not noticed that I am asking from the point of view as an invitee and NOT a meeting organiser

Comment: 'but why should I have to do that?' - because it's Microsoft ;)

Answer (score 12):

Not possible unfortunately. You can vote here https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-2016-for-windows/suggestions/20398333-provide-a-feature-to-cancel-a-recurring-meeting-wi

Comment: the link is no longer valid :(

Answer (score 11):

Had the same issue (as attendee who did not organize it).
In Outlook 365 app, I **clicked** on the **Appointment** in **calendar view** and at the ribbon bar a new tab **Meeting Series** occur with **Recurrence** where I can set the End Date.

[image: Appointment Reccurrence]

**BUT** I think in this case the meeting organizer is not informed, it's just removed from my calendar!

Comment: This doesn't seem like it ought to work, but it just did for me.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to change the "End By" date within the recurrence settings of the series.

1. Open the entire series of the meeting(s) in question.
2. Open the **Recurrence** dialogue box. *(see screenshot below)*
3. Select and change the **End By** date.

I'm using Outlook 2013, but you can Google "Recurrence tab + Outlook version" to work out where it's located if your Outlook differs.

[image]

Comment: I just tested this and it worked. Once I made the change, I clicked "Save & Close" in the top left. If OP is still around, this answer should be ticked.

Comment: @EngineerToast been quite a while lol ;d

Comment: That is something the organizer of the meetings can do – I believe the OP was asking for a way to decline a meeting series from a particular date onwards.

Comment: @MartinGeisler, it still works to hide the meeting from the calendar though. The only drawback is that the organizer will not receive a _decline_ notification.

Comment: Meeting has a recurrence set, and I am viewing the series, but I cannot edit the recurrence as the attendee.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question per @MartinGeisler comment above

Comment: You can do this even as an invitee. The key for me was to click on the meeting in my calendar pay, don't open the meeting, just click on it.  Then you will see reoccurrence at the top and you can click on it and put an end by date then it no longer shows up on your calendar beyond that date but it doesn't send a decline notification to the creator.

Answer (score 2):

As the **invitee** (the person invited, not the organizer) it is still not possible to decline *future* meetings in MS Outlook / MS Office.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cancel-all-future-meetings-in-a-series-9eaeee8c-bfe3-46a0-a092-9a2707f3b133

> *If you're not the meeting organizer, you can't edit the meeting details, so to remove all future meetings in a series from your calendar, you'll need to delete the meeting series.*

Answer (score 1):

So after landing here after searching for exactly the same, I believe that as of 2022 the only answer is to create a macro that will do the following:

- Macro will ask for specific series and the date range to cancel
- Decline all relevant meetings but only send a response to the first meeting in the series with a custom message informing the organizer about the date range that you are not joining anymore. Then do not send a response to all the other meetings that are being declined (just to prevent spamming the organizer)
- The organizer will now have the appropriate status for each meeting (even if you did not send a response it will be captured) and has received only 1 e-mail to inform about the meeting that was planned the soonest that you're not joining until a certain date or indefinitely

So now that I have typed out the idea, I might actually give this a shot since I have need for it, I'll post it if it works out (and if you are viewing this in 2025, know that I failed).

Answer (score -2):

It worked on my mac book pro by going to outlook 2011 version 14.5.7, 
go to calendar. Open calendar->
see Home-> appointments series-> organize-> tools.
Click on appointments series. 
Go onto the specific meeting/appointment/class, etc. You want to start by higlighting it then open your appointment screen and you have subject, location, starts, ends, and below that you have : recurrence :

For example: I have in my case a specific class every two weeks starting jan 09 /2014  and at the end of this line you have two little arrows  (looking like they turn like a wheel). Click on it.  You will have a pop up screen, then you choose from there the starting and ending times. (I had put unlimited) so I finally put an :"end time"

Hope it is clear and helpful ..(this is for outlook for mac)

Comment: This would be editing the actual event series for all the people invited, which is not the same as declining a meeting invite.

Answer (score -4):

It's actually much simpler than that. Simply go to your calendar and find the meeting placeholder at each recurring date. You can then accept each instance separately.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! On this Q&A site we try to provide [good answers](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) to questions people ask. Part of providing a good answer is making sure you fully read the question and understand what's being asked. In this case, the asker mentions that they are aware of the decline one option, which is what you're describing. Please update your answer to actually help resolve the question, or remove it.

Comment: The meeting is defined multiple times per week for the next year. You seriously think I'm going to go and individually decline each one of those?